# Regex matching mixed RTL and LTR String in Java

Tags: java, regex, arabic, right-to-left

I am receiving a JSON response from an Arabic transliteration service.

As a first step I tried to extract just the part of the response with the transliterated words using the following `Pattern`: `"\"r\":\"(\\P{M}\\p{M}*)*?\"");`. When I output the entire selection, this part of the response is correctly returned:

```
"r":"تست\\\/0|طست\\\/1|تسة\\\/1|طسة\\\/1|تيست\\\/1|طاسة\\\/1|تيسة\\\/1|تصت\\\/2|تثت\\\/2|تسط\\\/2"
```

However, when I try to get just the group part with `m.group(1)`, the output is `2`. I was expecting all the word parts between `"r":"` and `"`.

When I try selecting the entire console output in Eclipse, it appears that `"r":` is LTR and the rest is RTL. Perhaps that breaks the regex.

How can I get the entire group between `"r":"` and `"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are repeating the group. Your basic structure is like

```
(matchCharacter)*?
```

So group `1` only captures one character and not the entire string. Every time the group is used again, the previous capture is overwritten. This is why you get the last characters (which is the left-most one, due to RTL writing).

Just, wrap the entire repetition in a group, and make the repeated part non-capturing:

```
"\"r\":\"((?:\\P{M}\\p{M}*)*?)\""
```

This applies regardless of RTL or LTR writing. Only, if you use pattern you had originally, you will either get the left-most or right-most character, depending on direction (as it will be the last character in memory).